# What type should I be getting to dismiss a recommendation via the Google Ads API in Python?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I need to use Python in Google Colab to dismiss recommendations from many managed Google Ads accounts using the Google Ads API. I have been using the docs and the GitHub examples to build my code and it has worked to an extent. I have been able to retrieve recommendations with their resource names, but I have not been able to dismiss the recommendations. It seems there is an error getting the DismissRecommendationOperation.

Here is the code (with sensitive info redacted) and error message:

```
client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("google-ads.yaml.txt", version="v10")
customer_id = "XXXXXXXXXX"
recommendation_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


rec_service = client.get_service("RecommendationService")
operation = client.get_type("DismissRecommendationOperation")
operation.resource_name = recommendation_service.recommendation_path(
    customer_id, recommendation_id
)

response = rec_service.dismiss_recommendation(
    customer_id=customer_id, operations=[operation]
)

print(
    "Dismissed recommendation with resource name: "
    f"'{response.results[0].resource_name}'."
)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/ads/googleads/client.py in get_type(self, name, version)
    440             type_classes = self._get_api_services_by_version(version)
--> 441             message_class = getattr(type_classes, name)
    442         except AttributeError:

2 frames
AttributeError: unknown type 'DismissRecommendationOperation'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/ads/googleads/client.py in get_type(self, name, version)
    442         except AttributeError:
    443             raise ValueError(
--> 444                 f"Specified type '{name}' does not exist in "
    445                 f"Google Ads API {version}"
    446             )

ValueError: Specified type 'DismissRecommendationOperation' does not exist in Google Ads API v10
```

I have been using the docs here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/recommendations
and the GitHub example here: https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/23b6342914b49fa50e1c82b67f6508d2ac721787/examples/recommendations/dismiss_recommendation.py

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in the example. You can access the `DismissRecommendationOperation` through the `DismissRecommendation` request
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v10/DismissRecommendationRequest

```
request = client.get_type('DismissRecommendationRequest')
operation = request.DismissRecommendationOperation
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got this error `AttributeError: DismissRecommendationOperation`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using `proto_plus = False` in my config file, which apparently does not work with this wording. This is the code that worked for me:

```
def dismiss_the_recommendation(client, recommendation):
  rec_service = client.get_service("RecommendationService")

  request = client.get_type("DismissRecommendationRequest")
  operation = request.operations.add()

  operation.resource_name = recommendation.resource_name

  response = rec_service.dismiss_recommendation(
      customer_id=customer_id, operations=[operation]
  )

  return (f"Dismissed recommendation with resource name: {response.results[0].resource_name}.")
```

As a side note, I tried using the suggested solution with `proto_plus = True` and it still did not work, though I did not try very hard to debug it since I had already gotten this working.

I got the code that worked for me from GitHub [here](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/issues/596)